# Laravel 5.3 auth check in constructor returning false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I'm using `Laravel 5.3` and I'm trying to get the **authenticated** user's `id` in the `constructor` method so I can filter the user by assigned company as follows:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests ;

    public $user;
    public $company;


    public function __construct()
    {


        $companies = Company::pluck('name', 'id');
        $companies->prepend('Please select');
        view()->share('companies', $companies);
        $this->user = User::with('profile')->where('id', \Auth::id())->first();
        if(isset($this->user->company_id)){
            $this->company = Company::find($this->user->company_id);
            if (!isset($this->company)) {
                $this->company = new Company();
            }
            view()->share('company', $this->company);
            view()->share('user', $this->user);
        }

    }
```

However this doesn't return the user `id`. I've even tried `Auth::check()` and it doesn't work.

If I move the `Auth::check()` out of the `__construct()` method then this works as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        dd(\Auth::check());
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

However this **fails** if I put this in the construct method in the `HomeController` too!

Any ideas why this is failing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors)

> you can't access the session or authenticated user in your
>   controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>
> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly
>   in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure
>   that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * All of the current user's projects.
     */
    protected $projects;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->projects = Auth::user()->projects;

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN mine is 5.3.4 and it can't do you know how to upgrade to your version?

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN Done and work exactly like what you have said, thank you

Answer (score 9):

Since 5.3 `Auth::check` will not work in a controller's construtor, it's one of undocumented changes. So, you need to move it to middleware or do check in controller methods instead or move project to 5.2.x.

Comment: really? i didn't realise that! crap

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin, It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Comment: Thank you. but how did you know?

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you call `$this->middleware('auth');` after `parent::__construct();`. It means that you auth middleware is not loaded properly.

Comment: I've put it after the parent::__construct(); and it doesn't make a difference. I've even removed the middleware and no difference. do you have a code example?