# ErrorException in HomeController.php line 27: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm on Laravel 5.3 and I'm using view and I intend to share a variable globally to all of my views and this global variable contents the user's info who is currently logged in.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use View;

//use models
use App\profile;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        View::share('user_info',profile::where('username',Auth::user()->username)->get());

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $current_page = 'home';
        return view('pages.home');
    }
}
```

but unfortunately it gives me this error

> ErrorException in HomeController.php line 27: Trying to get property
>   of non-object

and the line 27 is this line

```
View::share('user_info',profile::where('username',Auth::user()->username)->first());
```

it seem's like the problem is 'Auth::user()->username' because If I manually specify the username, it gives me the collection I need.

Any ideas, help please?

here's my AuthenticatesUsers.php which I used to modify the authentication stuffs.

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;


trait AuthenticatesUsers
{
    use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Show the application's login form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

        if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the user login request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

    /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * The user has been authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  mixed  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        //check user role
        return redirect('/app/system/dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe just redirect back to login page if Auth::user is not defined (logged in) to prevent that kind of error `if (!Auth::check()) {
    redirect('/login');
}`

Comment: @NewbeeDev: why I have to do that?

Comment: you are getting the Auth::user() but you are not logged in Auth::user returns empty. the Auth::user will be only filled if you are logged in

Comment: @NewbeeDev I did make sure I'm logged in. I tried 'if (!Auth::check()) { redirect('/login'); }' just to check if I'm really logged in and it did not redirect me to the login page instead it redirects me to the admin dashboard page for logged users

Comment: try `var_dump(Auth::id());` and see if it has result just let me see the result of that

Comment: I tried 'dd(auth()->check()) ' on the constructor and it returns false but if I do 'dd(auth()->check()) ' on the 'public index()' it returns true. Any ideas?

Comment: @NewbeeDev: please see my updated post, I have included there the 'AuthenticatesUsers.php' which I used to modify the authentication stuffs. not much of a thing there, I just change the email to username and redirect to '/app/system/dashboard' instead of 'home' which is default

Comment: use `Auth` not `$this->guard()`

Comment: @NewbeeDev I tried your answer but sadly it does not work like same error, same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're running this code when user is not logged in, so you could do a check:

```
View::share('user_info', auth()->check() ? profile::where('username', auth()->user()->username)->first() : null);
```

This code will return profile or `null` if user is not logged in.

Comment: I did make sure I'm logged in. I tried your answer and it doesn't produce any errors but I tried to call it from the view blade like "{{ $user_info->username }}", it throws me this error "Trying to get property of non-object" any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon, you should check what does `dd(auth()->check())` return. If it returns `false`, then you have some auth related issue (you think user is logged in, but it's not).

Comment: I tried 'dd(auth()->check()) ' putting unto the constructor and it returns false and I tried to put it in the 'public index()' and it returns 'true' any ideas? this is confusing. Why when I 'dd' on the constructor, it return false but If 'dd' it unto the 'public index()', it returns true?

Comment: @CodeDemon, it's normal for 5.3. `check()` will not work in a construcor since 5.3, please look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186222/laravel-5-3-auth-check-in-constructor-returning-false

Comment: So, it seems your authentication works fine. What does `dd()` show if you put it right before `View::share()`?

Comment: are you referring to 'dd(auth()->check());' to be put before the 'view:share()' Sir?

Comment: it returns false and even after view::share(), it returns false.

Comment: Ok, problem described in this [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-auth-in-service-provider-to-get-user-object/replies/79555) Also, try the solution from this [topic](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-auth-in-service-provider-to-get-user-object?page=1), guy said it works for him.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```

to

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
}
```