# Access Auth in parent constructor in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, constructor, controller

Im working on an app in Laravel 5.3. I have created an `AppController`. I would like for all of my controllers to extend `AppController` so that they all share a few common properties and methods.

Given the below 2 implementations below, my intention is to set the current user to `$this->user` when `AppController` is constructed so it will be available to all controllers extending `AppController`.

I expect that when I call `\App\Http\Controllers\User\PermissionController@test` I should get my user object dumped twice. Once when `AppController` is initialized, and again when `PermissionController@test` is called.

However, inside of `AppController __construct()`, `$this->user` is always `NULL` while `PermissionController@test` dumps the user as expected.

#### AppController:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\App;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class AppController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * The current user when logged in
         * @var \User
         */
        protected $user;

        public function __construct()
        {
            if(\Auth::check() ) {
                $this->user = \Auth::user();
            }
            var_dump($this->user);
        }
    }
```

#### PermissionController:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

    use App\Http\Controllers\App\AppController;

    class PermissionController extends AppController
    {
        public function test()
        {
            if(\Auth::check() ) {
                // Do something
                $this->user = \Auth::user() ;
            }
            var_dump($this->user);
        } 
    }
```

If it matters, I'm using https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel to auth against Active Directory.

**Clearly I'm misunderstanding something hear. Why does `AppController __construct()` not dump the user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of changes in Laravel 5.3. If you need to use Auth in constructor you need to do it like so:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
             if(\Auth::check() ) {
                $this->user = \Auth::user();
            }
            var_dump($this->user);

            return $next($request);
        });
}
```

This change was described in upgrade guide to Laravel 5.3 - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0 look at section **Session In The Constructor**

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was losing my mind. One note, we have to `return $next($request);` from the middleware function,  [see this question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/errorexception-in-verifycsrftoken?page=1)

Comment: @DelightedD0D Right, I've added this to answer

Answer (score 1):

The controller construct executes before any middleware, so there is no user yet (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0)

You can use closure middleware as described in the guideline.

From the docs

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or
>   the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was
>   never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel
>   5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet

As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = auth()->user();

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188299/1227923).

You need to move this check in middleware if you're using Laravel 5.3