# laravel - Can't get session in controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, session, constructor

In new laravel I can't get session in constructor. Why?

```
public function __construct()
{
    dd(Session::all()); //this is empty array
}
```

and then below

```
public function index()
{
    dd(Session::all()); //here works
}
```

In old laravel i remember there was not this problem. something changed?

Comment: Because you shouldn't, really.

Comment: Why not, somethings you do some auth checks from session

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't do it by default with Laravel 5.3. But when you edit you `Kernel.php` and change `protected $middleware = [];` to the following it wil work.

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Are you sure this will not break session functionality for routes inside `web.php` or something? Did you test it?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin with my Laravel project everything works fine, I moved the last 2 from the `web` array.

Comment: @gogagubi nice, if this works you can show other users that this works fine through accept this answer!

Comment: I got another problem by adding these lines. Sessions between controller and view don't work.

Comment: But i found solution. I have commented same two line in $middlewareGroups array and now it works.

Comment: Yes, that's true, you also need to remove the lines from you web. I updated my answer!

Comment: For this to work in Laravel 6.x, I had to remove all previous sessions from session driver as well.

Answer (score 16):

Laravel 5.7 solution

```
public function __construct()
{

$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
// fetch session and use it in entire class with constructor
$this->cart_info = session()->get('custom_cart_information');

return $next($request);
});

}
```

If you want to use constructor for any other functionality or query or data then do all the work in $this->middleware function, NOT outside of this. If you do so it will not work in all the functions of entire class.

Comment: @Miron I did not test it with Laravel 7.0 yet but good to hear that it works also in Laravel higher version 7.0. Thanks dear :)

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me in Laravel 7. Searches for a solid hour and then it's so easy…

Comment: I tryed this with Laravel 8, and I can confirm that is working

Answer (score 11):

As of other answers no out of the box solution for it.
But you still can access it using Middleware in constructor.

So here is another hack

```
public function __construct(){
    //No session access from constructor work arround
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next){
        $user_id = session('user_id');
        return $next($request);
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how/why this works? I can't figure it out on my own

Comment: THIS SOLUTION IS NOT WORKING.. PLEASE SUGGEST HOW YOU DID IT.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Worked on Laravel 8.

Answer (score 6):

In [Laravel 5.3 sessions related functionality will not work in the a controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188299/1227923), so you should move all sessions related logic to methods.

Comment: This also goes for Laravel 5.4.

Comment: laravel 5.6 - same

Comment: Is there some kind of callback in which i could check stuff, that would be called after the constructor but before the actual function?

Answer (score 3):

As of Laravel 6.18.1, add these to `$middleware` array in the kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is coming across this question in now, instead of accessing session values in controller constructors, I will suggest creating a middleware and placing it in the Web middleware section in the `App\Http\Kernel`.

This is because sessions are not part of the requests that are passed to Controller constructors. To then do any session value checks or manipulation in every controller, it is safer to create a middleware.

This is where session values can be accessed as part of the HTTP request going into the route.

```
`/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
        ...,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\MySpecialMiddleWareToAccessSessionVariables::class
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];`
```

This is because `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` has started the session before it hits your routes

Answer (score 1):

Add these two at the bottom in $middleware array in the app\Http\kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
```

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *This one solved mine problem to use session in constructor* 
   $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if (!session('records_per_page')) {
            session(['records_per_page' => 20]);
        }

        // update rows per page
        if (!empty(\Request::get('records_per_page')) && in_array(\Request::get('records_per_page'), [20, 50, 80, 100])) {
            session(['records_per_page' => \Request::get('records_per_page')]);
        }
        return $next($request);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Session in the construct using middleware, You can try, It would be helpful

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('PM');

    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next){
        $school_id = Session::get('school_id');


        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: I used Session in the construct using middleware, You can try, It would be helpful