# Laravel session out the box not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've created a new laravel installation and the first thing I'm trying to do it just confirm sessions are working:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $value = Request::session()->get('key');
    if (is_null($value)) {
        Request::session()->set('key', md5(rand()));
    }
    dd(Request::session()->get('key'));

    return view('welcome');
});
```

I'm hoping here that session 'key' is stored, then, on the next refresh, it will output (dd) the same key value each time. However, it doesn't. I get a different value for 'key' each time. So I guess session data is not being stored?

If it helps, below is the config/session.php content:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
...
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
...
```

My .env has the following:

```
...
SESSION_DRIVER=file
...
```

And permissions on the folders are:

```
$ ll /var/www/o-eco/website/storage/framework
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Oct  3 02:33 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Oct  3 02:33 ../
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Oct  3 02:33 cache/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu www-data  103 Oct  3 02:33 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Jan 13 10:59 sessions/
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Jan 13 10:59 views/

$ ll /var/www/o-eco/website/storage/framework/sessions
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Jan 13 10:59 ./
drwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu www-data 4096 Oct  3 02:33 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu www-data  258 Jan 13 10:59 5xqzOeb6f5lLKyvZIwOeonutkmluREfcaQ5owTNE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu www-data   14 Oct  3 02:33 .gitignore
```

Note: this time, I'm developing within a vagrant box so all files are ubuntu:www-data. Also, I've even tried setting the sessions dir/files to 777 but still no difference.

Also, I have two cookies: XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session. These both remain unchanged on each refresh.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet but don't you need the user and group of PHP to read/write to those files. Do you have anything in your logs?

Comment: dont use the request class, use Session::get();

Comment: Checkout my answer, hope it works! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor/41542867#41542867 Let me know if this works!

Comment: Hi Robin. Thanks for the reply. No, it didn't work. Same result.

Comment: I changed to Session::get/put but just the same. Nothing appearing in my log either - `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log` or `tail -f /var/log/apache2/eco-error.log`

Comment: If you change your `SESSION_DRIVER=database` and `php artisan session:table && php artisan migrate`, did this work?

Comment: Hi Robin, I tried switching sessions to "database" as you suggested. Still same result. I can see the value of env('SESSION_DRIVER') in the app is now "database" but nothing is being written to the sessions table. I done a similar switch to redis yesterday. I could even see related activity in `redis-cli monitor` when I refreshed the page, but nothing was actually stored and the variable wasn't stored. I'm working now within a vagrant box, yesterday was on the host machine. Same result both times. So strange.

Comment: Seems if I call Session::save(); after the put(), it stores. Is this usually required? Maybe I've missed something from the docs, I'll check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `save();` after put it will works

Just try this

```
Session::put('key', md5(rand())); 
Session::save();
```

**EDIT**

removed `dd()`

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $value = Request::session()->get('key');
    echo $value;
    if (is_null($value)) {
        Request::session()->set('key', md5(rand()));
    }

    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: Hi. Just the same result, doesn't matter if I use `Request::session()` or `Session::` or `session()` it seems.

Comment: Just try to apply `save()` after `put()`. `Session::put('key', md5(rand()));
Session::save();`

Comment: Hi. Yeh it saves when I run Session::save(); afterwards. But do I need to call this every time?

Comment: Yes because some times `Laravel` application lifecycle starts, any value put in Session are not yet stored until the application lifecycle ends.

Comment: @Martyn Hope your problem is solved so accept and upvote my answer for helping other to find solution

Comment: It's helpful, thanks, but not really the solution to this problem. It seems I'm calling save() here because something isn't working properly when storing variables in session. There is no mention of save() in the documentation so I'm still searching for the reason why sessions aren't working as written in the docs.

Comment: @Martyn the route you have defined is in web.php?

Comment: Yes, it is in routes/web.php

Comment: hey @Martyn just solved your issue. I have updated my answer just check it

Comment: Yes! I see now what's happened. The app was being halted and the framework wasn't writing to session huh. Great. Thanks for your time and patience.