# Laravel5.3 missing the Session data between route to route

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

I am using the `Session::put('page', $page)` to setting the `callback` function `redirect url`, but it is some problem, when I `dd(Session::all())` can`t find the data that I had been set, any Idea?

my `Controller`

```
public function getAuth(String $type,String $page)
{
  Session::put('page', $page);
  return Socialite::driver($type)->redirect();
}

public function callback(String $type,Request $request)
{
  dd(Session::all());
  $social = Socialite::driver($type)->user();

  switch (Session::get('page')) {
    case 'create': $route = 'User.Register.Create'; break;
    case 'login' : $route = 'User.Login.Social'   ; break;
  }

  return redirect(route($route))->with(compact('social'))->with('provider',$type);

}
```

Here is the `dd(Session::all())` look like:

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "VMEvO7VJU8mMpFKLt03LjXaXkB38rHlBR86tlz5z"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▶]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▶]
]
```

`config/session.php`

```
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => true,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => false,
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

ps :the code I paste can be run successfully `dd()` the `page` arg in my localhost.

Comment: when you will do dd(). you page will die and you might not be able to get all session

Comment: @ Vikash
I change my code  `$page=Session::get('page'); echo $page; ` and remove the `redirect()` the page echo the null result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `/storage/framework/sessions` permission to this folder and also

Just remove the `dd(Session::all())` It will not print the `Session` information instead of it just `echo` the value it will works.

Just check my other answer here

> [Laravel session out the box not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633766/laravel-session-out-the-box-not-working/41633962#41633962)

Comment: ,I am trying to add `Session::save()` after `Session::put('page', $page)` and `$page=Session::get('page'); dd($page)`,
but it is still not work, a null given, by the way, the original code I pasted `page ` arg can be see in `dd(Session::all())`

Comment: `/storage/framework/sessions` check this folder has `permissions`