# laravel 5.4 controller constructor could not get session variable value even it exist in another method from same controller

Tags: laravel-5.4

I have write NewsController in my laravel application after
 login/signup I set some value in session like 'admin_user_id'
 below.but i am not getting this session variable value in constructor but   same varible value I get in 'announcements' function of same controller.   any idea ?

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Request;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use View;
use Config;

    class NewsController extends Controller {  
        public function __construct() {
           echo Session::get('admin_user_id');die;
        }
        public function announcements() {
            echo Session::get('admin_user_id');die; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: if someone do not understand. please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty common question. This is because the session middleware has not run yet which returns blank.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor) or [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15072).