# session(['key' => 'value']) and session()->get('key') returns null

Tags: php, laravel, session

Login method where the access_token is generated :

```
        $response = $this->api_client->request(
            'POST',
            '/oauth2/token',
            ['form_params' => $data]
        );

        $response_body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        **$access_token** = $response_body['access_token'];

         //var_dump($access_token) -> returns the token

        session(['access_token'=>$access_token]); //dd() on this returns null
```

On dumping the '$access_token' it returns the auto generated token, but when I'm trying to assign it to session() with 'key' => 'value' pair it returns null.

I am currently using laravel 5.5 and even tried it using 'Sessions', still having the same issue.Is there any possible way to use this '$access_token' in another class or repository with the actual data getting passed.

The controller in which I'm trying to access the token :

```
public $apiClient, $contentClient, $accessToken;

public function __construct(Dropbox $dropbox)
{
    $this->apiClient = $dropbox->api();
    $this->contentClient = $dropbox->content();
    $this->accessToken = session('access_token');
}
```

I have searched the web and haven't found a satisfied answer to this particular issue. Could you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel - Can't get session in controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor)

Comment: How could you see this as a possible duplicate @Script47

Comment: You are trying to access session variables in the constructor?

Comment: Check if your route is under the auth or web middleware because that handle sessions.

Comment: Yes. It is under a custom ['middleware' => ['admin'], under route group. What should I change in order to access the session('key')? @JesusErwinSuarez

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 'admin' middleware then try adding 'web' middleware too in your route, it something look like this.

```
'middleware' => ['admin', 'web']
```