# \Request::getSession() returns NULL in Controller construct

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the session id of the user each time a page is loaded so I use \Request::getSession()->getId() in the controller construct but I get this error

```
Call to a member function getId() on null
```

If I use same code in any of the route methods, it works.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // No session access from constructor work around
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        \Request::getSession()->getId();
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; Auth::getSession()->getId();`

Answer (score 0):

This is the default functionality of Laravel. Session data is no longer available in the constructor. See:

[laravel - Can't get session in controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

Taylor's word about it :

It’s very bad to use session or auth in your constructor as no request has happened yet and session and auth are INHERENTLY tied to an HTTP request. You should receive this request in an actual controller method which you can call multiple times with multiple different requests. By forcing your controller to resolve session or auth information in the constructor you are now forcing your entire controller to ignore the actual incoming request which can cause significant problems when testing, etc.