# Laravel session won't change

Tags: session, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to change website language using the "site_lang" session key. Here's the **Controller**

```
public function __construct()
{

    if( !session()->has( 'site_lang' ) ) { session(['site_lang' => 'en']); }
    $this->lang = session()->get('site_lang');
    app()->setLocale($this->lang);
```

User clicks another language link to change website lang so he gets redirected to this function in the HomeController which extends **Controller**

```
session()->forget('site_lang');
session(['site_lang' => $lang]);
//echo  session()->get('site_lang').'<br>'; //prints fr
$this->lang = $lang;
//echo $this->lang; //prints fr
app()->setLocale($lang);
//echo app()->getLocale(); //prints fr
return redirect("/");
```

Removed some validations to make it brief

So the user clicks "French" and gets redirected to "HomeController@change_lang" which is the previous function and all echo statements prints **fr** but when the user gets redirected to the home page the value gets assigned again to **en** by this line

```
if( !session()->has( 'site_lang' ) ) { session(['site_lang' => 'en']); }
```

Why does this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: as stated in the answer below, you do not have access to the session in the constructor because the request has not passed through the middleware stack which has a middleware that starts the session ... also as said below in a comment, you should most likely not be doing this logic in the constructor of a controller, it is more than likely better in a middleware

Answer (score 0):

SESSION can't be accessed from the constructor unless following a work around like [laravel - Can't get session in controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor#thisanswer-41542867)

Comment: Constructors are not meant to contain any logic.