# How can I get my session data inside my constructor function in the controller

Tags: php, laravel, constructor

This is a part of the code.

```php
        class StudentController extends Controller
        {
                public function __construct(Request $request) 
                {
                    $school = session('school_data');

                    $this->middleware($school); 
                }
        }
```

Now, I've also tried checking the `$school` by using `dd($school)` but it returns `null`

NOTE: The session variable works in other functions inside the same controller.

Comment: Is this controller instantiated by dependency injection? If so, I'm guessing that the session might not be available yet.

Comment: I just decided to write it there manually, how can I use the dependency injection

Comment: I already placed the Illuminate\Http\Request at the top of the file

Comment: This won't work. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just need to place the middleware guard inside dynamically because there are lot of guards for each different school

Answer (score 0):

your sessions are not ready yet.
if you want to use them, use like below:

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request) 
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            // fetch session and use it in entire class with constructor
            $this->school_data = session()->get('school_data');

            return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

from here: [laravel - Can't get session in controller constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542802/laravel-cant-get-session-in-controller-constructor/55887660)