# Get Auth User id in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Recently i upgraded from laravel 5.2 to laravel 5.4. I was getting current logged user from below code

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    protected $user_id;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }
}
```

The above code was working fine in 5.2 version. After upgrading to 5.4 i am getting

> Auth::user()->id as NULL

How to fix this??

Comment: auth()->user()->id should work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39188299/1227923