# Laravel Auth : Returning false in controller

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am using laravel 5.5 . I am using this for authentication.

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password'),'is_activated'=>1])
```

But : when i login ,and i do: `Auth::check()` in layout , it return true. But when i do same thing in controller it return false.
To be exact, I am checking `Auth::check()` in constructor in controller.
Can any one tell me , how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u just check in controller by `middleware` not `auth` check like that not `Auth::check()`

**try to check by middleware**

```
 public function __construct()
    {
          $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

becuase **middleware is not running before auth so always throw fals**e in constructer but u get true in any controller method .

try to check `Auth::check()` in controller method more detail [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186222/laravel-5-3-auth-check-in-constructor-returning-false)

Comment: As i ,have not configured the "Auth :: path " for lgout and login ..and doing it manually.. How can i achieve this: I know we can do it via middleware , but is there no any other option.

Comment: Thanks, I used the middleware and give " Route::get('/sign-in', 'UsersController@sign_in')->name('login');"    in route and it works