# Lavarel Auth::check() not woking

Tags: php, laravel

I check login at UserControler: Auth :: check () == true;

```php
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
{
   var_dump(Auth::check());
}
```

but check login at `Controller: Auth :: check () == false;`

Please help me understand it. Below is my code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

   function __construct()
   {
       $this->checkLogin();
   }

   function checkLogin()
   {
      var_dump(Session::get('user'));
           view()->share('user_login', Auth::user());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Laravel 5.3 auth check in constructor returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186222/laravel-5-3-auth-check-in-constructor-returning-false)

> you can't access the session or authenticated user in your
>   controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>
> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly
>   in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure
>   that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

Comment: Can you say clearer?
I am using Laravel version 5.6

Comment: you should use laravel middleware to check if user is logged in, as said above "you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet."